# Retrieve Image source by class or id with php and javascript/JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, jcarousel

What i'm trying to do is i have an image display on the page and another image lays on top with many frames selection implemented by JQuery from the following tutorial:

http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel

With JCarousel, one of the images from many selected will be assigned with "active" class to the

and the each of the images are within list, for example

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></li>
```

What i want to do is to get the image src location with "active" state (class) whenever user click or select and pass into php. Does anyone mind to offer some suggestion or tips on how can i do that?

Thank you for your time reading my Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jQuery should select what you want in JavaScript:

```
var activeImageSource = $('li.active').find('img').attr('src');
```

As for passing it to PHP, it depends on how you are submitting information. You could submit the *src* via an [HTTP `<form>` POST](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) (where the `action` is the PHP file that is coded to parse the request) or via an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request. You can access the *posted* data in the PHP [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array.

#### JavaScript

```
var activeImageSource = $('li.active').find('img').attr('src');

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'some.php',
  data: 'activeImage=' + activeImageSource,
}).done(function(msg) {
  console.log('Success');
});
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
  echo 'activeImage source is ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['activeImage']);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply andyb :D i'm really appreciate for your help. However, my problem is i couldn't pass a javascript variable/data to PHP. From my understanding passing variable/data from JavaScript to PHP are impossible, am i correct? anyway, thanks again for helping, i'm really appreciate :)

Comment: You could POST a JavaScript variable to PHP via the two methods in my answer. I have edited my answer with an AJAX example.

Comment: Thanks andyb, sorry for the late reply. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. really appreciate with your help. thanks again